# Is the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ contained in the domain of $(-\partial_x \alpha(x) \partial_x)^{1/2}$?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, differential-operators

Let $\alpha(x) : \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ have bounded variation (BV) and suppose $\inf_{\mathbb{R}} \alpha > 0$. Consider the second order differential operator
$$H : =-\partial_x (\alpha(x) \partial_x) : L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
It's not too hard to show that
$$ \{u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : u, u' \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and } Hu \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \} \\
= \{u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : u, \, \alpha u' \text{ are locally absolutely continuous and } Hu \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\},
$$
and that $H$ is self-adjoint with respect to this domain $\mathcal{D}(H)$, which is a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

> I would like to know whether the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in the domain of the square root operator $H^{1/2}$ (defined via the spectral theorem).

Recall the well-known fact that $\mathcal{D}(H^{1/2})$ is equal to the form domain associated to $H$ (i.e., the completion of $\mathcal{D}(H)$ with respect to the norm $\| u\|^2_{+1} := \langle Hu,u \rangle_{L^2} + \langle u,u \rangle_{L^2}  \approx \|u\|^2_{H^1}$.)

If $\alpha$ has some more regularity, for instance if $\alpha$ is $W^{1, \infty}$ instead of merely having BV, then it is immediate that $C_0^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{D}(H) \subseteq \mathcal{D}(H^{1/2})$. So in that case, for any $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, if we approximate $u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ by a sequence $u_j \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$, these $u_j$ are also Cauchy with respect to $\| \cdot \|_{+1}$, and hence $u \in \mathcal{D}(H^{1/2})$.

We don't necessarily have the inclusion $C_0^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{D}(H)$ in the BV case. But can we come up with a different subspace of functions contained in $\mathcal{D}(H)$, that has a sequence converging to $u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and Cauchy with respect to $\| \cdot \|_{+1}$? This is where I am stuck.

Comment: How is $Hu$ defined in the left-hand side of the first display (when we only know that $u'$ is bounded)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks for your question. In that case $\alpha(x) u'(x)$ is a locally integrable function and I am taking $Hu = -(\alpha u')'$ to be the derivative of $\alpha u'$ in the sense of distributions. I have a proof (using integration by parts and Cauchy-Schwarz) that the two domains I wrote are equal.

Comment: This seems very reminiscent of the issue of showing that $H$ is densely defined for such operators. When $\alpha$ is sufficiently nasty (just locally integrable), no obvious dense subspace of $D(H)$ comes to mind, and one has to work harder to show this. (I can't remember how exactly this is usually done, but Weidmann's Springer lecture notes discuss the topic.)

Comment: @JZS: I see. Regarding the question: by the spectral theorem, the domain of of the square root operator $H^{1/2}$ is the same as the domain of the quadratic (Dirichlet) form associated with $H$, which in this case coincides with the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb R)$, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually do this directly and my comment above is not that relevant. Let $u\in H^1$ and also assume that $u$ is compactly supported, so $\int u'=0$. Approximate $\alpha u'$ in $L^2$ by $v_n\in C_0^{\infty}$. Here we can also insist that $\int v_n/\alpha=0$. Then also $v_n/\alpha\to u'$ in $L^2$, so $u_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x v_n/\alpha\, dt\to u$ locally uniformly and thus $u_n\to u$ in $H^1$.

Clearly, $u_n\in D(H)\subseteq D(H^{1/2})$, and as you already explained yourself, this implies that $H^1\subseteq D(H^{1/2})$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain a little more why without loss of generality we can assume that $\int v_n/\alpha = 0$? I see this is needed so the $u_n$ are in $L^2$. I tried to take generic $v_n/\alpha$ and "project away from constants" but this didn't work for me.

Comment: I think the key is that we also have $v_n/\alpha\to u'$ in $L^2$, so automatically $\int_{-L}^L v_n/\alpha\to 0$ (where we take $L$ so large that this interval contains the support of $u$). Now we can add a piece on $[L,L+1]$ of small norm that makes the integral exactly zero.

Comment: I think another way to see the reduction is as follows. Fix $\phi_0 \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}; [0,1])$ with $\int \phi_0/\alpha = 1$, and then replace $v_j$ by $v_j - (\int v_j/\alpha) \phi_0$.

Comment: @JZS: That looks good, too. By the way, the only thing we use about $\alpha$ here is that $0<c\le \alpha\le C$, so the statement is also true for any such (locally integrable) $\alpha$.